# What is the different between LoG (Laplacian of Gaussian) filter, first and second derivative Gaussian filter?

Tags: image-processing, filter, laplacianofgaussian

What is the different between LoG (Laplacian of Gaussian) filter, first and second derivative Gaussian filter?

Is it second derivative Gaussian filter equal to Laplacian Operator?

[image]

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/db5/tutorial_laplace_operator.html

When I search online, there are different shape said that is second derivative Gaussian filter. So which one is correct?

[image]
http://www.me.umn.edu/courses/me5286/vision/VisionNotes/2017/ME5286-Lecture7-2017-EdgeDetection2.pdf (P.39)

[image]
https://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/e27_s2016/filter-slides.pdf (P.31)

[image]
http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture11_6pp.pdf (P.3)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Laplace is defined as the sum of second order partial derivatives. As in the equation you show.

In the first image, *f* is not a Gaussian, *f'* is. Thus *f"* there is the first derivative of the Gaussian. The other image shows the 2nd derivative of a Gaussian.